# Brightness control not working on HP Pavilion dm3t (Intel GMA 4500MHD)

Tags: 10.10, intel-graphics, hp, brightness

I picked up an hp dm3t laptop with intel HD graphics and installed ubuntu 10.10 64 bit on it. It works great -- the only problem is that the brightness controls on the keyboard don't work. The brightness is always at full. When I try to adjust it down, the indicator graphic indicates that it's going down but the actual brightness doesn't change. Is there anything that I can try to make this work? I'd really appreciate any help.

I asked this on [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/) and someone commented that I should play around with the intel hd drivers. I'm a total noob -- how do I do that? What else can I try? I really don't want to go back to windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a kernel bug.

You might be interested in reading this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/568611), where an Ubuntu kernel developer posted a [link to his PPA](https://launchpad.net/~kamalmostafa/+archive/linux-kamal-mjgbacklight) with a patched kernel (including steps on how to install it).

Comment: This doesn't apply to my graphics driver

Comment: You have an Intel GMA 4500MHD and comments in this bug report suggest that the patched kernel fixes the very same problem with this GPU (eg. #111, #112).

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm having trouble finding steps on how to install it. The patched kernel is here: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git?p=kamal/ubuntu-maverick.git;a=shortlog;h=refs/heads/mjg-backlight   ... I can't seem to find the directions on how to install it. Are they in the README inside of the download? If so, which section do I follow (there seem to be multiple options.)

Comment: @James: You don't need to compile your own kernel. Just add the PPA to your system. Start a terminal and run `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:kamalmostafa/linux-kamal-mjgbacklight`, then `sudo apt-get update` and finally run the upgrade with `sudo apt-get upgrade`. As you can read in the above link to the PPA, you might need to add `acpi_backlight=vendor` to the linux-line of the grub entry for the new kernel (see the comments in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16669/how-to-completely-backup-entire-ubuntu/16687#16687) about how to add parameters to the kernel during boot).

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Change the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` into

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux"
```

Run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Restart your Linux

Credit to [this guy](http://livinginjava.blogspot.com/2010/11/ubuntu-1010-brightness-problem-in-acer.html)

Comment: This doesn't allow me to change the brightness. Also, the indicator that the brightness is being changed is gone.