# Kernel compile error with iw_ndis.c

Tags: 10.10, kernel, intel-graphics, compiling

I have a hp pavilion dm3t with intel HD graphics running ubuntu 10.10 64 bit. I'm trying to compile and install a patched kernel according to this,
https://launchpad.net/~kamalmostafa/+archive/linux-kamal-mjgbacklight

So I downloaded the tarball from here (linked to from the page above): 
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git?p=kamal/ubuntu-maverick.git;a=shortlog;h=refs/heads/mjg-backlight

I untar'd it to a directory, entered the directory and did:

```
make defconfig
```

I'm not sure if that's what I should have done but it was successful, so I did:

```
make
```

which seemed to work fine until it gave these errors:

```
ubuntu/ndiswrapper/iw_ndis.c:1966: error: unknown field ‘num_private’ specified in initializer
ubuntu/ndiswrapper/iw_ndis.c:1966: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
ubuntu/ndiswrapper/iw_ndis.c:1967: error: unknown field ‘num_private_args’ specified in initializer
ubuntu/ndiswrapper/iw_ndis.c:1967: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
ubuntu/ndiswrapper/iw_ndis.c:1967: warning: (near initialization for ‘ndis_handler_def’)
ubuntu/ndiswrapper/iw_ndis.c:1970: error: unknown field ‘private’ specified in initializer
ubuntu/ndiswrapper/iw_ndis.c:1970: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
ubuntu/ndiswrapper/iw_ndis.c:1970: error: initializer element is not computable at load time
ubuntu/ndiswrapper/iw_ndis.c:1970: error: (near initialization for ‘ndis_handler_def.num_standard’)
ubuntu/ndiswrapper/iw_ndis.c:1971: error: unknown field ‘private_args’ specified in initializer
ubuntu/ndiswrapper/iw_ndis.c:1971: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
make[2]: *** [ubuntu/ndiswrapper/iw_ndis.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [ubuntu/ndiswrapper] Error 2
make: *** [ubuntu] Error 2
```

How can I compile and install this kernel successfully? I'm new to this and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I found, but there was no answer

Comment: For the iw_ndis.c problems see my answer at http://askubuntu.com/questions/30636/10-10-error-compiling-kernel-in-iw-ndis-c/31784#31784

Answer (score 2):

Considering your last question about your laptop [backlight](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19380/brightness-control-not-working-on-hp-pavilion-dm3t-intel-gma-4500mhd), you don't need to compile the kernel to use the patch. You just need to add the PPA to your system's Software Sources.

[htorque](https://askubuntu.com/users/3037/htorque) explained how to proceed in his [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19380/brightness-control-not-working-on-hp-pavilion-dm3t-intel-gma-4500mhd/19382#19382) :

> Just add the PPA to your system. Start a terminal and run `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:kamalmostafa/linux-kamal-mjgbacklight`, then `sudo apt-get update` and finally run the upgrade with `sudo apt-get upgrade`. As you can read in the above link to the PPA, you might need to add `acpi_backlight=vendor` to the linux-line of the grub entry for the new kernel (see the comments in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16669/how-to-completely-backup-entire-ubuntu/16687#16687) about how to add parameters to the kernel during boot).

The whole process is already detailed at the bottom of [the page you linked](https://launchpad.net/~kamalmostafa/+archive/linux-kamal-mjgbacklight).

Answer (score 0):

The num_private and num_private_args fields are only defined when  CONFIG_WEXT_PRIV is defined during kernel compilation hence you need to add the #ifdef/#endif lines here to iw_ndis.c:

```
const struct iw_handler_def ndis_handler_def = {
    .num_standard   = sizeof(ndis_handler) / sizeof(ndis_handler[0]),
#ifdef CONFIG_WEXT_PRIV 
    .num_private    = sizeof(priv_handler) / sizeof(priv_handler[0]),
    .num_private_args = sizeof(priv_args) / sizeof(priv_args[0]),
#endif
    .standard   = (iw_handler *)ndis_handler,
#ifdef CONFIG_WEXT_PRIV 
    .private    = (iw_handler *)priv_handler,
    .private_args   = (struct iw_priv_args *)priv_args,
#endif  
    .get_wireless_stats = get_iw_stats,
};
```

However, that's not all. You'll also then get an error compiling wrapndis.c <s>so you need to find the lines with the following if statement (at approx line 1820) and wrap that up in an #ifdef/#endif.</s>

<s>#ifdef CONFIG_WEXT_PRIV

if (wnd->physical_medium == NdisPhysicalMediumWirelessLan) {
net_dev->wireless_handlers = &ndis_handler_def;
}#endif</s>

Should add that I am trying to compile this myself and have not tested ndiswrapper having done this so YMMV.

The above for wrapndis is wrong, it seems that CONFIG_WIRELESS_EXT is not set in (my) kernel configuration. If it was then I shouldn't get this error.