# Error compiling kernel in iw_ndis.c

Tags: 10.10, kernel, compiling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Kernel compile error with iw_ndis.c](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19478/kernel-compile-error-with-iw-ndis-c)

I just wanted to compile a kernel (as described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile#Alternate%20Build%20Method:%20The%20Old-Fashioned%20Debian%20Way)), but I got this error:

```
ubuntu/ndiswrapper/iw_ndis.c:1966: error: unknown field ‘num_private’ specified in initializer
ubuntu/ndiswrapper/iw_ndis.c:1966: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
ubuntu/ndiswrapper/iw_ndis.c:1967: error: unknown field ‘num_private_args’ specified in initializer
ubuntu/ndiswrapper/iw_ndis.c:1967: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
ubuntu/ndiswrapper/iw_ndis.c:1967: warning: (near initialization for ‘ndis_handler_def’)
ubuntu/ndiswrapper/iw_ndis.c:1970: error: unknown field ‘private’ specified in initializer
ubuntu/ndiswrapper/iw_ndis.c:1970: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
ubuntu/ndiswrapper/iw_ndis.c:1970: error: initializer element is not computable at load time
ubuntu/ndiswrapper/iw_ndis.c:1970: error: (near initialization for ‘ndis_handler_def.num_standard’)
ubuntu/ndiswrapper/iw_ndis.c:1971: error: unknown field ‘private_args’ specified in initializer
ubuntu/ndiswrapper/iw_ndis.c:1971: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
```

Can anyone tell me what it means? Googling just came up with a result here on this site, where there was no answer, so maybe now someone knows.