# Can't adjust brightness on a HP Pavillion Dv3

Tags: 11.10, screen, brightness, hp, hp-pavilion

I can not adjust the screen brightness on my HP Pavillion Dv3-2154ca, using Ubuntu 11.10. My Fn-f7/f8 keys don't work (they just show a changing screen brightness bar, with no effect), and adjusting 'screen brightness' does nothing as well.

I'm new to Ubuntu/Linux, so simple answers would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I think that your problem is similar to [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19380/brightness-control-not-working-on-hp-pavilion-dm3t-intel-gma-4500mhd). Because you use Ubuntu 11.10, you don't have to change the kernel, because kernel 3.0 is already patched with the fix. But, according to what is reported in the specified [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~kamalmostafa/+archive/linux-kamal-mjgbacklight), you may still need a fix to the boot options:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Change the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` into

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

Run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Restart Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

1. `sudo -H gedit /etc/rc.local`
2. Before the `exit 0` statement, write

   ```
   echo your_brightness > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
   ```

   where `your_brightness` means a number (1 - 10).
3. Example `echo 5 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`
4. Reboot

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget:  You will need to run `sudo update-grub` if you want the changes in `/etc/default/grub` to be there when you reboot!

Comment: I think this was supposed to be a comment on the previous answer? :)